# javascript map and join on an array

Tags: javascript

```
d = [
    ["a", "Adobe"]
    ["b", "Boston"]
    ["c", "Cars"]
    ["d", "Dominos"]
    ["e", "Microsoft"]
]
const asString = d.map(function(x){
        x[0],'=',x[1]
    }).join('&');
  console.log(asString);
```

I'm trying to generate a query string from the above array, but seem to be getting only `&&&&`. The original solution used Template Literals and was like this:

```
const asString = d
      .map(x => `${encodeURIComponent(x[0])}=${encodeURIComponent(x[1])}`)
      .join('&');
  console.log(asString);
```

This works fine, but I don't want to use Template Literals.

The end result is a querystring like this: `a=Adobe&b=Boston&c=Cars&d=Dominos&e=Microsoft`

Comment: `d.map(x=>x.join("=")).join("&");`

Answer (score 2):

You could take the key and value and return the new strings.

```js
const
    d = [["a", "Adobe Photoshop"], ["b", "Boston"], ["c", "Cars"], ["d", "Dominos"], ["e", "Microsoft"]],
    asString = d.map(([key, value]) => key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value)).join('&');

console.log(asString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning any values from your `map` callback:

```
d.map(function(x){
        x[0],'=',x[1]
    }).join('&');
```

should be:

```
d.map(function(x){
        return x[0] + '=' + x[1]
    }).join('&');
```

"Classic" style functions don't return values in the same way as lambda (arrow) functions do, so you need to explicitly return the value.

Answer (score 1):

Just using map and join:

```js
const d = [
    ["a", "Adobe"],
    ["b", "Boston"],
    ["c", "Cars"],
    ["d", "Dominos"],
    ["e", "Microsoft"]
]
let queryString = d.map(x=>x.map(encodeURIComponent).join("=")).join("&")
console.log(queryString)

// Without arrow function
queryString = d.map(function(x){
  return x.map(encodeURIComponent).join("=")
}).join("&");

console.log(queryString)
```

Comment: How would you do this without using arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce`

```js
d = [
    ["a", "Adobe"],
    ["b", "Boston"],
    ["c", "Cars"],
    ["d", "Dominos"],
    ["e", "Microsoft"]
]
 let join = d.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
    return acc + elem.join("=") + '&'
 },"");
 
 console.log(join.slice(0, -1))
```